# how to select one by one elements in the list view using single button (play button)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create event player. That means all the elements in the list view should select one by one and should scroll down that list automatically when click the button.

[jquery Selectable](https://jqueryui.com/selectable/)

i want this selector clicking single button.when click that button should select one by one items automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Have a look at iterators: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Comment: What have you tried till now ? share the code

Comment: Show code, we can't help and we won't do your job